# SORRY YOUR 'APP' unfurtunately stoped or can't launch

Tags: android

I constantly have this message when I launch my app !!!SORRY YOUR APP unfortunately stopped or can't launch. I don't really know how it came about. Can some help me out with this error please. Equally I don't get any error message after launching only when app has to launch.

here is the logcat error message:
and its layout activity
my main activity code

```
01-02 12:52:57.694 5065-5065/com.logo.tm.logodrive001 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.logo.tm.logodrive001, PID: 5065
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.logo.tm.logodrive001-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:110)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:753)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setTitleInt(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:261)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setWindowTitle(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:243)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowTitle(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:621)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onTitleChanged(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:631)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.logo.tm.logodrive001.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

```java
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mDriver, mCustomer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDriver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.driver);
        mCustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customer);

        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, onAppKilled.class));
        mDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DriverLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });

        mCustomer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CustomerLoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.logo.tm.logodrive001.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log in 1"
        android:id="@+id/driver"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log in 2"
        android:id="@+id/customer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide your code please.

Comment: (Failure to lunch?) Anyway, the message "No static method getFont" is the first thing to investigate, for which you/we need the code.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont is your answer.... but now u need to dig deeper into the getFont method. Please post it above.

Comment: which pleace code

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use support lib's custom fonts. You need both build-tools and support lib v26 or higher for that.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the TOOLBAR TextView. Please post relevant code of Toolbar.

Comment: which the style values